# Error: Index out of bounds when using windRose function in Openair package on Mac Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: r, osx-yosemite, openair

I can't use windRose (or even pollutionRose) in R (Rstudio) because of the `Error: index out of bounds` error even when applying on the included dataset (mydata) with the package.  I reinstalled and loaded `dplyr`, `lazyeval`, `maps` packages just in case they were outdated.

The exact code I used was

```
library(openair)
data(mydata)
windRose(mydata)
```

I tried on Windows 7 version of Rstudio and it worked.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got it to work but I had to remove and install all packages `openair` require such as

`dplyr`,
`maps`,
`lazyeval` (from reading the forums, it seems this package is the source of the “`Error: index out of bounds`” error)
...and then install `openair`.